# Java: How to abstract between "regular" TCP Socket and SSLSocket

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, tcp, sslsocketfactory

Edit: Removed `startHandshake();` as it's irrelevant to the question and rarely needed (for example, not in my case)

I have a rather specific and rare client-server protocol (over TCP).
I've implemented it using SSLSocket.
Now, I foresee that I might need to use the same protocol over an un-encrypted connection.

My problem is that the class implementing the protocol has a field: `public SSLSocket currentSocket;`

(and then the methods in my client class do all sorts of `.read(), .write(), flush()...`)

I thought about changing the field type, like so: `public Socket currentSocket;`

However, then, the problem is that my connection procedure is incompatible:

```
public static void connect () {
currentSocket = SslUtils.getSSLsocket(host, port, keystoreFile, keystorePass, pkPass);
...
```

- java.net.Socket 's default constructor obviously doesn't accept keystore stuff

I don't want to re-implement my whole client just for this difference...

- One thought I have is, when I need a plaintext Socket, to create an SSLSocket with no encryption.
  I don't know if that's a professional way of doing it or if it will even work (the server will expect a plaintext client socket in the new use case)
- My other idea is to define two fields, one for plaintext socket, one for SSL socket and then use logic to link the in/out streams to the correct field, as needed. However, that will result in a "hanging" field. If you use SSL, there will be a redundant field `Socket plaintextSocket` and vice-versa...

Is there a way to make my `currentSocket` field more abstract, so that I can define it in the same client, then instruct a slightly different client code path depending on a known variable (something like `needSSLsocket=true`) for the instantiation and connection?

Comment: (1) You can write your own factory that creates the socket required, and (2) you don't need to call `startHandshake()`. You should be able to write your entire application in terms of `Socket`, other than what happens in the factory method, unless you are doing fancy stuff like session invalidation or re-handshaking.

Comment: @user207421 I thought about my own factory but it looks like more fuss than it's worth. I got pretty well contained use cases. As for startHandShake - I am afraid I am a prisoner of ignorance here. I don't know how to connect an SSL socket without it. Anyway, thanks for your valuable input!

Comment: `startHandshake()` is called automatically on the first I/O to/from the socket. You don't have t call it yourself. You only need to call it when you want to rekey the session.

Comment: @user207421 YES! I simply commented out that handshake and things work as usual :) To be honest, when developing my client, I had to deal with so much, I didn't question every piece of guidance I was able to find. One less action means a lot in my style of developing - thank you <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SSLSocket` extends `Socket`, so you can assign an `SSLSocket` object to a `Socket` variable.  You are right to change your `currentSocket` field to a `Socket`.  Simply use another variable to handle the `SSLSocket` when needed, eg:

```java
public static void connect () {
    if (needSSLsocket) {
        SSLSocket ssl = SslUtils.getSSLsocket(host, port, keystoreFile, keystorePass, pkPass);
        ssl.startHandshake();
        ...
        currentSocket = ssl;

        /* or:
        currentSocket = SslUtils.getSSLsocket(host, port, keystoreFile, keystorePass, pkPass);
        ((SSLSocket) currentSocket).startHandshake();
        ...
        */
    } else {
        currentSocket = new Socket(host, port);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Tested and adopted. Thank you! I will just add a comment about startHandshake();

Comment: OK that edit was rejected but for future readers: startHandshake(); , as shown in my question and irrelevant to it, may not be an essential part of an SSL socket connection procedure, except in rare cases.

Comment: @DraxDomax "*startHandshake(); , as shown in my question **and irrelevant to it***" - then you should have left it out of the question altogether to begin with.

Comment: to be honest I thought I could leave it there. As, from an objective point of view, another coder might actually need to call that method and it shows things you cannot perform on a Socket object, adding to the impetus to bridge the types. But I'll be damned to argue with 400k :) I will edit. Thanks again for your help